# .NetCore 5 session is not starting after publish

Tags: asp.net-core, session, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working with .NetCore API and MVC. Everything works on the local server. But the session does not occur after publishing the site.
The operation of the project is as follows:

1. User come with token ID to website.
2. I'm parsing it and then saving important variables to session.
3. I'm getting values from session.
   ...

As you can see If I get error on session other steps will fail.
I tried too many ways but none of them worked.
I'm adding Startup.cs/ConfigureServices and Configure methods.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();

        services.AddWkhtmltopdf("wkhtmltopdf");
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(600);//You can set Time   
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
        services.AddAuthentication();

        services.AddScoped<Business.Business, Business.Business>();
        services.AddSingleton<SharedViewLocalizer>();
        #region Localization and Language
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var cultures = new[] {
                new CultureInfo("tr-TR"),
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("de-DE"),
            };
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
            options.SupportedCultures = cultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = cultures;
        });
        #endregion

        services.AddMvc(option =>
        {
            option.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
        })
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
            opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; })
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

                
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();

            }
            #region Language Options
            var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            var cookieProvider = options.Value.RequestCultureProviders
                .OfType<CookieRequestCultureProvider>()
                .First();
            var urlProvider = options.Value.RequestCultureProviders
                .OfType<QueryStringRequestCultureProvider>().First();

            cookieProvider.Options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("tr-TR");
            urlProvider.Options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("tr-TR");

            cookieProvider.CookieName = CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName;

            options.Value.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
            options.Value.RequestCultureProviders.Add(cookieProvider);
            options.Value.RequestCultureProviders.Add(urlProvider);
            app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
            #endregion

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            #region Routing
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    "areas",
                    "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                //endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                //endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Home");
            });
            #endregion

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None` must be used to allow cross-site cookie use.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-5.0

The order of middleware is important. Call UseSession after UseRouting and before UseEndpoints. See Middleware Ordering.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0

If your production environment consists of multiple servers, the easy way out (but not the recommended way), is to enable sticky sessions in your load balancer.

Using distributed cache is the recommended way when using multiple servers. More info: https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-session-storage-strategies

You should consider not to use sessions at all, that will make things a lot easier for you.

Comment: I've changed the order of UseSession() and republished. It didn't work. It creates just Culture cookie. You can see on 'ionya.7hills.net' web site. I'm using token on every page changes. When it's not avaible, its crash.

Comment: I can handle error easily like the way you offer but i need to create session.

Comment: @emroo: What kind of environment are you using? E.g. IIS, Azure, AWS BR

Comment: We are using IIS.

Comment: @emroo: This should fix the problem: `options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None`

Comment: Thank you. I've changed this minimum settings and it works now.